# Javascript find function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, find

I have an array and trying to use find method and it doesnt give be expected result but i get it via foreach.  Sorry I cann't provide array, because i dont have it . I tried for a long time but didn't find a mistake. Hope its enough.

When i am using that foreach it works

```
products.product.forEach(function(p) {
  p.composition.id === id);
}
```

But it doesnt work here

```
let currentProduct = products.product.find(pr=> {pr.composition.id===id});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you're not returning the boolean of the condition from the `.find`. Try this:

```
let currentProduct = products.product.find((pr) => {
    return pr.composition.id === id;
});
```

Or even just without the curly braces:

```
let currentProduct = products.product.find((pr) => pr.composition.id === id);
```